# Woltjer's Theorem, partial or total derivative?

Tags: astrophysics, plasma-physics

Morning everyone.. I am currently studying Plasma Physics on a recent book named "Basics of Plasma Astrophysics" by Claudio Chiuderi and Marco Velli. While demonstrating [Woltjer's Theorem](http://www.pnas.org/content/44/6/489.full.pdf) they state the equivalence between the total and partial derivative of the magnetic helicity, and I am failing to understand why. What's the reason behind this?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see an "equivalence between the partial and total derivative" of H in anything you've written; it's always written $dH/dt$ as a total derivative. The reason that the partials emerge within the volume integral is because A and B are also functions of *space*, and so the time derivative must be taken while holding position constant; it's basically that:

> $\frac{d}{dt} \int_V d^3r ~ f(\vec r, t) ~=~ \int_V d^3r ~\frac{\partial f}{\partial t} $

So, on the left-hand side, that quantity has no space-dependence (you integrated it away); as long as we don't have something like $V = V(t)$ where the volume we're integrating is changing in time, and if $f$ is "nice" in the usual physical sense, then the above equation holds just because they're independent variables.